# SQL query performance is slow: number ranges and numbers

Tags: sql, performance

Working with oracle SQL.
Got two tables: first contains number ranges, second has numbers. 
The result I need is the first table plus numbers from the second table which are not in the first tables number ranges.

```
table ranges
LOW_RANGE            HIGH_RANGE
1000000000000000000  1000000099999999999
4253525250000000000  4253525259999999999
4352000000000000000  4352999999999999999

table numbers
NUMBER        LENGTH (implies that the rest of the numbers are 0-9 range)
100000000000  12(max)
100000000051  12
425252525100  10
435252525000  9
425353000000  6
797689600000  9

needed result:
LOW_RANGE     HIGH_RANGE
100000000000  100000009999  (ranges)
425252525000  425252525999  (ranges)
435200000000  435299999999  (ranges)
425353000000  425353999999
797689600000  797689600999
```

I've got this solution:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTR(ranges.LOW_RANGE,1,9)||'000'
  ,SUBSTR(ranges.HIGH_RANGE,1,9)||'999'
FROM
  ranges
UNION ALL
SELECT
   numbers.NUMBER
  ,RPAD(SUBSTR(numbers.NUMBER,1,numbers.NUMBERLENGTH),12,'9')
FROM
  numbers b
WHERE b.NUMBER NOT IN
(
  SELECT b.NUMBER
  FROM ranges a
  WHERE b.NUMBER BETWEEN SUBSTR(a.LOW_RANGE,1,9)||'000' AND SUBSTR(a.HIGH_RANGE,1,9)||'999'
)
```

Which works but is very slow for big datasets. Is there any other faster solution?

Edit: modified question

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, please show the actual operations being performed, along with the string operations.  This makes a big difference to performance.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Modified question to have string operations. These string operations and a few DECODEs for other unimportant fields are the only operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string manipulation is usually slow in databases.

My personal recommendation is change the tables' structure and modify everything to numbers.

```
table ranges
LOW_RANGE_START LOW_RANGE_END HIGH_RANGE_START HIGH_RANGE_END
100             000           101              999
```

and same thing with Numbers table

```
table numbers
RANGE_START RANGE_END
100         999
```

Then rewrite your queries to use numbers, will be much faster. especially if you index your data properly.

Comment: Modifying table structure isn't an simple thing, unfortunately. So, last resort only.

Comment: since SUBSTR, RPAD are deterministic functions, you can create a function based index on your fields, that should accelerate your queries a bit.

Comment: Here is more about range queries and Indexing http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates
And Function Based Indexes:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php

Comment: Neat, will definitely try that!

Comment: Surprise surprise adding new indexes for a single view doesn't please db admins :( Still wondering if it's possible to do it with some SELECT magic.

Comment: I don't like your admins, Does a slow running query please them more? Anyways, I guess I'm out of ideas. If I think of something I'll get back to you.

Comment: Well, it's sort of logical to assume that it's just a badly written query and could be done in a better way. Once it's clear that there is no way to rewrite it, then probably it's index time.